# How to Implement the constraints satisfaction problem which can solve Odd/Even/Prime Sudoku puzzle in Python?

Tags: python, sudoku, puzzle

**Following is the complete detail, Please help.**

Implement the constraints satisfaction problem which can solve Odd/Even/Prime Sudoku puzzle.  You have to define the constrains, find domains, variables and non empty domain of possible values of each variable. After defining constrain use backtracking algorithm to solve the puzzle. Please read following instruction carefully for the development of program.

To solve the puzzle, player has to fill 9x9 grids with single digit numbers (1 to 9). Out of 81 cells 9 cells are green color cells and their position is fixed. Remaining 72 cells are either gray or white colored. Gray and white colors are randomly allocated to the cells at the beginning of the game. Within the rows and columns are 9 “squares” (made up of 3 x 3 spaces). Each 3x3 space must have one green color cell at the center. Each row, column and square (9 spaces each) needs to be filled out without repeating any numbers within the row, column or square. Green colored cells must be filled with prime numbers (2, 3, 5, and 7). Gray color cells must be filled with odd numbers (1,3,5,7,9) and white color cell must be filled with even number(2,4,6,8). At the beginning of the game 25% random location must be filled with numbers.

Hint: In 3x3 sub space 4 cells must be gray in color; central cell has green color, and remaining 4 cells are white in color.

**Note: I have implemented only the simple Sudoku puzzle in python.**

Simple Sudoku Puzzle code in Python:

```
    board = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]


def solve(bo):
    find = find_empty(bo)
    if not find:
        return True
    else:
        row, col = find

    for i in range(1,10):
        if valid(bo, i, (row, col)):
            bo[row][col] = i

            if solve(bo):
                return True

            bo[row][col] = 0

    return False


def valid(bo, num, pos):
    # Check row
    for i in range(len(bo[0])):
        if bo[pos[0]][i] == num and pos[1] != i:
            return False

    # Check column
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        if bo[i][pos[1]] == num and pos[0] != i:
            return False

    # Check box
    box_x = pos[1] // 3
    box_y = pos[0] // 3

    for i in range(box_y*3, box_y*3 + 3):
        for j in range(box_x * 3, box_x*3 + 3):
            if bo[i][j] == num and (i,j) != pos:
                return False

    return True


def print_board(bo):
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - ")

        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
            if j % 3 == 0 and j != 0:
                print(" | ", end="")

            if j == 8:
                print(bo[i][j])
            else:
                print(str(bo[i][j]) + " ", end="")


def find_empty(bo):
    for i in range(len(bo)):
        for j in range(len(bo[0])):
            if bo[i][j] == 0:
                return (i, j)  # row, col

    return None

print_board(board)
solve(board)
print("___________________")
print_board(board)
```

[image: Output of above code]

Comment: I have updated my question with my code which I have tried to implement sudoku puzzle in python language.